# Long running MVC action execution is it going to stop if the user closes the page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, execution, long-running-processes

I have long running data processing on one page. It takes 3 minutes - that is an operation done by the admin and it is not executed very often.

What will happen if the user closes the page? I suppose if that user have more tabs or pages opened to the same site, the execution will continue otherwise will stop. Is that correct thinking?

Comment: It shouldn't affect it. The server doesn't know that the browser has closed the page.

Comment: Also, test it! Make an experiment and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

When an `ASP.NET` page runs, the page goes through a `life cycle` in which it performs a series of processing steps. These include initialization, instantiating controls, restoring and maintaining state, running event handler code, and rendering.

All your code will be running no matter if the client is there or not to receive it . as @DLeh mentioned in his comment The server doesn't know and doesnt' care if the browser has closed the page.

check this out for more info  [MS Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#general_page_lifecycle_stages)